# Jersey Response with JSONP

Tags: jersey, jsonp

I am creating a Jersey API service to be called from browsers and java clients. The code works when called from the same domain, but when called from some other domain it did not work, so I created a tried to wrap the responseJson String with JSONWithPadding. It is still sending the normal response back and not the response I am looking. The implementation of service is Jersey ( Maven Path Below:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Sample Code for

```
@Path("/v1/sample")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class SampleService
{
      @GET
      @Path("/service1")
      @Produces({"application/json"})
      public Response notWorking(@Context UriInfo uriInfo)
      {
        String result = "{\"name\":\"John Johnson\",\"street\":\"Oslo West 16\",\"phone\":\"555 1234567\"}";

        String callbackStr = (String)uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("callback");
        System.out.println("callbackStr ="+callbackStr);

        JSONWithPadding paddedJson = new JSONWithPadding(result, callbackStr);

        return Response.status(200).entity(paddedJson).build();
      }
}
```

call 1: http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/sample/service1
Response: {"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}

call 2: http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/sample/service1?callback=?
Response: {"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}

In call 2: Response I am looking for is 
?({"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"})

Surely I am missing something, but could not figure out.

Answer (score 1):

There was several things to work on in your example.

- JSONP needs one of the following response contentTypes: "application/javascript", "application/x-javascript", "application/ecmascript", "text/javascript", "text/x-javascript", "text/ecmascript", "text/jscript". It doesn't work with "application/json".
- You have to make sure that the name of the QueryParam recieved is called "callbackStr". It is usually called "callback".
- You can return directly the JSONWithPadding object.

  ```
  @GET
  @Path("/service1")
  @Produces({"application/javascript"})
  public JSONWithPadding nowItWorks(@QueryParam("callbackStr") String callbackStr, @Context UriInfo uriInfo)
  {
     String result = "{\"name\":\"John Johnson\",\"street\":\"Oslo West 16\",\"phone\":\"555 1234567\"}";

     System.out.println("callbackStr ="+callbackStr);

     return new JSONWithPadding(result, callbackStr);
   }
  ```

Hope this helps.